# (WINSOCK) C++ Game Server: Too many TCP connections at once on TCPAccept

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, ddos

I'm trying to do a stress test in case attackers try to attempt a lot of TCP connections to my C++ game server at once.

I made a simple program that connects 1000 times via the TCP port
to my game server. Here is where my server accepts connections:

```
bool serverIsOn = true;
double listen = tcplisten(12345, 30000, 1);
setnagle(listen, true);

...

while(serverIsOn){
    double playerSocket = tcpaccept(listen, 1);
    if(playerSocket > -1){
        cout << "Got a new connection, socket ID: " << playerSocket << endl;

        std::string ip = tcpip(playerSocket);
        if(ipIsBanned(ip))
            closesocket(playerSocket);
    }
}
```

Here are the definitions of tcplisten and tcpaccept:

```
double tcplisten(double port, double max, double mode)
{
    CSocket* sock = new CSocket();
    if(sock->tcplisten((int)port, (int)max,(int)mode))
        return AddSocket(sock);
    delete sock;
    return -1;
}

double tcpaccept(double sockid, double mode)
{
    CSocket*sock = (CSocket*)sockets.item((int)sockid);
    if(sock == NULL)return -1;
    CSocket*sock2 = sock->tcpaccept((int)mode);
    if(sock2 != NULL)return AddSocket(sock2);
    return -1;
}
```

**The problem:** **The server stops accepting connections after my test program has ended.** For example, if I connect on my game after (which only requests one connection as opposed to my test-attack program which requests 1000 connections), the game can not even connect. I also do not see any connections via console output on my server anymore. The last connection made was from the attack program. It's as if it can't accept anymore and something has crashed but I can't figure out what, no exceptions or errors.

This is a huge problem for my server as anyone can easily just crash the server and force it to have to restart to start accepting new connections again.

What can I do to combat this? I mean I tried even setting the max number of connections at once to 30,000 but that didn't work. Even if it did work, someone could just try to connect more than 30,000 times making that useless.

**EDIT:**

More in-depth definitions of tcplisten and tcpaccept functions above:

```
bool CSocket::tcplisten(int port, int max, int mode)
{
    if((sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET) return false;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    if(mode)setsync(1);
    if(bind(sockid, (LPSOCKADDR)&addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(sockid);
        return false;
    }
    if(listen(sockid, max) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(sockid);
        //TEMP ADD
        sockid = INVALID_SOCKET;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


CSocket* CSocket::tcpaccept(int mode)
{
    //TEMP REMOVE: if(sockid<0)return NULL;
    if(sockid == INVALID_SOCKET) return NULL;
    SOCKET sock2;
    if((sock2 = accept(sockid, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        CSocket*sockit = new CSocket(sock2);
        if(mode >=1)sockit->setsync(1);
        return sockit;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the definition of AddSocket:

```
int AddSocket(CSocket*b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sockets.count; i ++)
    {
        if(sockets[i] == NULL)
        {
            sockets.set(i, b);
            return i;
        }
    }
    sockets.Add(b);
    return sockets.count-1;
}
```

Comment: When you call `closesocket(sockid)`, make sure to also set `sockid = INVALID_SOCKET` afterwards.  And `sockid<0` should be `sockid == INVALID_SOCKET`.  And why are you using `double` to represent sockets instead of using `SOCKET` or at least `int`? `SOCKET` handles are not floating-point values. An what does `AddSocket()` actually return? You are passing that value directly to `closesocket()` if the IP is banned. Why are you not cleaning up your `CSocket` object for that client?

Comment: And the `max` value you pass to `listen()` does not control how many clients can be connected at a time, it controls how many clients can be pending in the socket's backlog waiting for `accept()` to accept them. You have to use your own logic to control the number of max clients connected at a time. If `accept()` returns an accepted client, and you have exceeded your max limit, close the socket immediately.  Or use `WSAAccept()` instead of `accept()` so you can use a callback function that rejects pending clients when your max limit has been reached.

Comment: Your situation sounds like either your `while(serverIsOn)` loop has stopped running, or `accept()` is blocked waiting for new clients that never arrive. But you have no output when socket functions fail, or any output after your loop ends.  Add those messages and then see what happens.

Comment: Amazing! I use that port number on my luggage!

Comment: Port numbers are not doubles either, they are 16-bit integers. This is very strange code.

Comment: Okay so a few things. I edited my first post with the changes you made Remy in your first comment. I also added definition of AddSocket().
Also the closesocket() I'm using is derived from the one declared in winsock.h. How would you propose I clean it up? Should I add a higher level closesocket() function that calls the one declared in winsock, but that also does something else? (Cleaning? Can you explain a bit more on what you mean I should do here).

Also, the while loop still runs. I added output in my lowest tcpaccept() function and nothing outputs when I try to connect with my game.

Comment: Also for your max solution, are you saying I should have a variable that keeps track of how many sockets/clients that have been connecting? Increment it by 1 each time I accept a new client, and then once the max is reached, reject clients from connecting? And then once I call closesocket(), decrement that variable by 1?

Comment: Uh, double for integers that must be preserved exactly? I have never seen that.

Comment: It's a library that was used specifically for another program that when using DLLs could only accept doubles. But that's really not the point here.

The point is tcpaccept() after my "attack" has for some reason stopped accepting connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you can use the [`tcp_tw_reuse`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.8/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt#L464) sysctl.

Comment: The server runs on Windows using winsock functions.